# Eyes and nose that are joined to the main mesh move / disappear when I use pose mode?

Tags: mesh

https://i.gyazo.com/fa9a48ca848c1ad06fd9d64cdc84073c.mp4

For some reason, whenever I manipulate my model in pose mode the nose detaches even though its a part of the base mesh that the body is on? It's frustrating me as im afraid I will need to completely delete the head and restart :( thank you.

Comment: I haven't done much rigging, but my guess is that you need to set the nose vertices' weights to 1 for the head bone.

Comment: Select the nose in Edit mode and assign it to the head vertex group in the Properties panel > Object Data > Vertex Groups